# CakePHP SaveAll not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I can't seem to get my edit class to work. My validation works fine and when I use debug($this->data) after hitting the edit button all the displayed data is perfect, but not updating the tables.

Here is my edit class.

```
public function edit($id = null) {
    if($this->request->is('get')) {
        $this->request->data = $this->Bookmark->read(null, $id);
    } else {
        if($this->Bookmark->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('The bookmark has been saved!');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('The bookmark could not be saved. Please, try again.');
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the view.

```
<?php

echo $this->Form->create('Bookmark', array(
    'action' => 'edit',
    'inputDefaults' => array(
        'class' => 'input-text'
    )
));
echo $this->Form->inputs(array(
    'legend' => false,
    'fieldset' => true,
    'Bookmark.title',
    'Url.url',
    'Bookmark.id' => array('type' => 'hidden'),
    'Url.id' => array('type' => 'hidden')
));
echo $this->Form->button('Edit');
echo $this->Form->end();

?>
```

I have updated my edit class, but that still didn't fix my error. What fixed it was the two hidden fields I added to the view.

```
    'Bookmark.id' => array('type' => 'hidden'),
    'Url.id' => array('type' => 'hidden')
```

Not really sure why, but I looked at some other edit views online and tried this and it now works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following this page:  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html

In Cake 2.0.x you should be using `$this->request->data`, though that's not likely the problem.  You'll also see they're not setting the id manually, but allowing the form to do that fom them.

If you try it as the book suggests, and it's still not working, post your new attempt as an Edit to this question.

Comment: I've tried it with request and read over that doc several times. The results are the same with or without the request part. When I remove $this->Bookmark->id = $id; the form stops pre-populating the form fields.

Comment: I should also add that if I use save instead of saveAll it will save the title, but not the Url. SaveAll saves nothing.

Comment: You shouldn't need that $id line - if you do, that's your first clue as to where the problem may lie.

Answer (score 0):

Each time this happend to me was because of validation error. Check for validation errors like so

```
echo debug( $this->ModelName->invalidFields() );
```

Comment: No need to echo here. Just debug.